# OpenGL ES on iOS Adding Vertices to Buffers

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rendering, buffer

In my app I am using OpenGL ES to render a file downloaded from the internet that is then parsed into a vertex array, so I have to input vertex and normals data after launch. I am new to OpenGL ES but I have been reading and learning. I have setup a vertex and normals buffer that seem to be working fine, but I think that I am putting the vertex and normals data into the buffers incorrectly because when I load the view there is an object there that vaguely resembles the shape that I want but with triangles veering off in various directions and parts of the shape missing. Here is my code for inputting my data into the buffers:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < triangle_cnt; i++) {
        int base = i * 18;
        GLfloat x1 = vertices[base];
        GLfloat y1 = vertices[base + 1];
        GLfloat z1 = vertices[base + 2];
        GLfloat x2 = vertices[base + 6];
        GLfloat y2 = vertices[base + 7];
        GLfloat z2 = vertices[base + 8];
        GLfloat x3 = vertices[base + 12];
        GLfloat y3 = vertices[base + 13];
        GLfloat z3 = vertices[base + 14];
       
        vector_t normal;
        vector_t U;
        vector_t V;
        GLfloat length;
       
        U.x = x2 - x1;
        U.y = y2 - y1;
        U.z = z2 - z1;
       
        V.x = x3 - x1;
        V.y = y3 - y1;
        V.z = z3 - z1;
       
        normal.x = U.y * V.z - U.z * V.y;
        normal.y = U.z * V.x - U.x * V.z;
        normal.z = U.x * V.y - U.y * V.x;
       
        length = normal.x * normal.x + normal.y * normal.y + normal.z * normal.z;
        length = sqrt(length);
       
        base = i * 9;
        verticesBuff[base] = x1;
        verticesBuff[base + 1] = y1;
        verticesBuff[base + 2] = z1;
       
        normalsBuff[base] = normal.x;
        normalsBuff[base + 1] = normal.y;
        normalsBuff[base + 2] = normal.z;
       
        verticesBuff[base + 3] = x2;
        verticesBuff[base + 4] = y2;
        verticesBuff[base + 5] = z2;
       
        normalsBuff[base + 3] = normal.x;
        normalsBuff[base + 4] = normal.y;
        normalsBuff[base + 5] = normal.z;
       
        verticesBuff[base + 6] = x3;
        verticesBuff[base + 7] = y3;
        verticesBuff[base + 8] = z3;
       
        normalsBuff[base + 6] = normal.x;
        normalsBuff[base + 7] = normal.y;
        normalsBuff[base + 8] = normal.z;

        fprintf(stderr, "%ff, %ff, %ff,          %ff, %ff, %ff, \n", x1, y1, z1, normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
        fprintf(stderr, "%ff, %ff, %ff,          %ff, %ff, %ff, \n", x2, y2, z2, normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
        fprintf(stderr, "%ff, %ff, %ff,          %ff, %ff, %ff, \n", x3, y3, z3, normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    }
```

And here is the code I use for using those buffers:

```
- (void)setupGL {
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

[self loadShaders];

self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(.05f, .55f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertCount*sizeof(verticesBuff)*3*2, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(verticesBuff) * vertCount * 3, verticesBuff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertCount*sizeof(normalsBuff)*3*2, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertCount * 3, sizeof(normalsBuff) * vertCount * 3, normalsBuff);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

_rotMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;

_quat = GLKQuaternionMake(0, 0, 0, 1);
_quatStart = GLKQuaternionMake(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
glClearColor(0.78f, 0.78f, 0.78f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

// Render the object with GLKit
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuff);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normalsBuff);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertCount); //*******************************

// Render the object again with ES2
glUseProgram(_program);

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertCount);
}
```

If I take those logs and paste them into the vertex array of a sample app using the code Apple supplies when creating an OpenGL ES app then the object renders beautifully, so I have deduced that I must just be putting the vertex data in wrong.

So can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong when entering the vertices and normals? Any help is appreciated.

Also this is what my render looks like:

[image: bad render]

And this is, in shape at least, what it should look like:

[image: good render]

Comment: You posted too little information. Add the code on how you use those buffers and your draw calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy and there might be quite a few problems. The one you are currently facing would seem to be:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

The stride parameter (24) should be `sizeof(GLfloat)*3` and same goes for normals. This is because you don't use interleaved vertex structure any more and now your position coordinates are tightly packed (that being said you can also use `0` as a stride parameter now). The result you produced with this bug is that only every second vertex was taken, others were dropped and when positions are all taken it starts drawing normals. Also if your normal pointer and offset are set correctly you are reading them beyond the buffer and should produce either crash or reading some other resources.